# Why did the CS resistor explode in this circuit?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, boost, power-factor-correction

I implemented the following PFC boost converter as shown in the second image and plugged it into 220V with the no-load condition but it exploded at the plug-in. The explosion happened in the sense resistor (R9 R10) the bridge rectifier is burned out and I think also the MOSFET. I have to mention that I didn't use the NTC in the circuit. What is my mistake? Is the problem the absence of the NTC?

[image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the MOSFET failed first (failed short-circuit), causing the coil to saturate causing high current to flow through the resistors which blew up because of that. I think the MOSFET would survive without the resistors, so I don't think they are the cause. Although, again, I'm no expert here.

Comment: I'd say either the excessive wiring inductance caused a voltage spike at MOSFET turn-off, which blew the FET.... or the excessive inductance caused the MOSFET to oscillate and commit suicide. In any case, this needs a proper PCB.

Comment: Yes, also the chip isn't going to like having its decoupling cap so far away, it has to dump a lot of current into the FET to drive it...

Comment: [AN2755 Application note](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/dd/ab/71/7a/f9/cc/43/c2/CD00195418.pdf/files/CD00195418.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00195418.pdf)

Comment: You connect up power and everything goes smoke.  Are you sure that surface is non-conductive?  Electrons are looking for a path to ground.

Comment: Wiring up a boost converter like this is not great. The wiring adds inductance that would make this very different from a regular PCB (and even on a PCB trace inductance needs to be considered.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I was going to say the same thing. Seeing this made me cringe.

Comment: at least get a wooden board and some nails and put together an ancestor of modern breadboards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inrush current through T1 and D1 to charge C6 will cause T1 to saturate.  If the converter tries to start with the saturated inductor, it's essentially a short and large current will flow into the FET and CS resistor.

This is mitigated by adding a diode to provide a path around the inductor during the inrush:

From the app note linked in the comments, see D1:

[image]

Having said that, your construction technique isn't suitable for power conversion so there could be a bunch of other things going on as well.

Also from the app note:

Layout hints:
The layout of any converter is a very important phase in the design process that sometimes
does not have enough attention from the engineers. Even if it the layout phase sometimes
looks time-consuming, a good layout does save time during the functional debugging and
the qualification phases. Additionally, a power supply circuit with a correct layout needs
smaller EMI filters or less filter stages which allows consistent cost savings.
The L6562A does not need any special attention to the layout, just the general layout rules
for any power converter have to be carefully applied. Basic rules are listed below, using the
EVL6562A-400W schematic as a reference. They can be used for other PFC circuits having
any power level, working either in FOT or TM control.

1. Keep power and signal RTNs separated. Connect the return pins of componentcarrying high currents such as C4, C5 (input filter), sense resistors, and C6, C7 (output
   capacitors) as close as possible. This point is the RTN star point. A downstream
   converter must be connected to this return point.
2. Minimize the length of the traces relevant to L3, boost inductor L4, boost rectifier D4
   and output capacitor C6 and C7.
3. Keep signal components as close as possible to each L6562A relevant pin. Specifically,
   keep the tracks relevant to pin #1 (INV) net as short as possible. Components and
   traces relevant to the error amplifier have to be placed far from traces and connections
   carrying signals with high dv/dt like the MOSFET drains (Q1 and Q2).
4. Connect heat sinks to power GND.
5. Add an external shield to the boost inductor and connect it to power GND.
6. Connect a ceramic capacitor (100 ÷ 470 uF) to pin #8 (Vcc) and to pin #6 (GND) and
   close to the L6562A. Connect pin #6 (GND) to the RTN star point (see 1)

Comment: thanks, @JohnD,   isn't it better to fix the inrush current problem with NTC as it is in reference topology presented in AN2761? the diode you've mentioned is used in a 400w PFC while this is an 80w one from the same company.

Comment: You would have to be sure that the magnitude of the inrush after the NTC was small enough so that the inductor doesn't saturate when the switch turns on.  And you would have to be sure that an AC dropout or switch off/switch on while the NTC is still fairly hot wouldn't lead to saturation either.  I'd recommend the diode.

Comment: The rules still apply whether it is 80W or 400W.  The have two big MOSFETs in parallel.  Getting any switcher to work is a PITA.

Comment: is it suitable to use the same diode (1N5406) in my 80w topology? is it ok to simply connect this diode? doesn't it have any further consideration?
another question; why CS mechanism is not able to detect the overcurrent due to the inrush plug-in current flowing through the CS resistor and turning off the mosfet?
@JohnD

Comment: @KMoradi Yes, you should be able to use the same diode.  Once the inrush has passed and the boost starts the diode is reverse biased and essentially out of the circuit.  The current sense isn't fast enough to turn off the FET when it's turned on into a high DC voltage with a saturated inductor.  However, as several people pointed out, your construction technique could also be a problem which could cause your circuit not to operate.